# How to combine two observable one after other?

Tags: angular

I have an Observable:

```
this.data$ = this.dataService.toGetAllData();
```

if I subscribe into this Observable, it will return this array of object:

```
this.dataService.toGetAllData().subscribe(response => console.log(response));

{
   id: "1"
   name: "test"
   systemId: "61a92ad360863a5a0346eca1"
},
{
   id: "2"
   name: "test"
   systemId: "61a92ad360863a5a0346eca1"
},
```

So, I need to combine to another call to another service to return the name of the system according to the ID.

```
this.system$ = this.systemService.getSystemById(id);
```

How to combine this two observable into my variable data and return something like this:

```
{
       id: "1",
       name: "test",
       systemId: "61a92ad360863a5a0346eca1",
       systemName:" System Test"
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) to create a new observable from the value emitted from the first, then use [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) to combine the two values into one final object:

```
import { map, switchMap } from "rxjs/operators";

this.system$ = this.dataService.toGetAllData().pipe(
  switchMap(data => this.systemService.getSystemById(data.id).pipe(
    map(system => ({ ...data, systemName: system.systemName }))
  ))
);

// then this.system$.subscribe(...) or whatever you need
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Stephen.
But its return me the result of the last one observable.
I edit my question, to be more clear about what I need in the moment

Comment: Use another call to `map`  to transform the output of getSystemById. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
systemdata : any

this.dataService.toGetAllData().subscribe(response => {
     this.systemdata = response;
     );  
}

this.system = this.systemService.getSystemById(systemdata.id)
       .subscribe(result => {
          // here you will have a result with system name 
       }
       
ngDestroy(){
//Since You are storing the subscribe value
this.system.unsubscibe()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As you have updated your problem, you need to use [mergeMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/mergeMap) instead of switchMap

EDIT:
based on the below comment I have updated this code. you can change HTTP get calls and return type. I am using `any` for example only.

```js
     this._httpClient.get<any[]>(<YOUR_URL>).pipe(
            mergeMap((d: any[]) => {
                const id = d[0].systemId;
                return this._httpClient.get(<YOUR_URL>).pipe(
                    map((res: any) => d.map(final => {
                        return {

                            id: final.id,
                            name: final.name,
                            systemId: final.name,
                            systemName: res.systemName

                        }
                    }))
                )
            })
        ).subscribe((out) => console.log(out) );
```

Comment: I edited again. I don't know why but it's not working. This time, instead I have an object to switch map, I have an array of object.

Comment: if systemid is the same for all objects and ur second call will return a single string data then it will be done in map operator.